# Tensorflow load model via cron job

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to load a predictive model using a python file via a cron job and Im running into issue. Here are the details. I can run python files just fine as shown in the first example here:

```
0,15,30,45 8-16 * * * /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin//python  /home/ubuntu/sol/aws_br_gt.py
```

but this second python file will not run as needed. The only different is - this one calls tensorflow to load a model:

```
00 8-16 * * * /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin//python  /home/ubuntu/sol/aws_br.py
```

Does anyone see anything Im missing?

As always - everything runs fine from the command line.

Comment: does the cron log show anything? `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Just that both files ran, but the second file updates a plotly chart when it runs and that isnt happening